# Trying to get the attribute of clicked object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the headers value from the object when I click on its link.

For the example I'm trying to get the value "2014_BUDGET" when I click on the link.

I've tried all sorts of variations.

- Tried getting .prop() instead of `.attr`.
- Tried searching `.closest('td')`
- Tried getting the parent `attr`.

All end with an alert with `'undefined'`.

Here is my code

```
<td headers="2014_BUDGET" class="MYCLASS"><a 
href="javascript: alert(  $(this).closest('td').attr('headers')  );">1</a></td>

<td headers="2014_BUDGET" class="MYCLASS"><a 
href="javascript: alert(  $(this).attr('headers')  );">1</a></td>
```

Answer (score 5):

In href this points to the global `window` object.

Use onclick instead.

```
<td headers="2014_BUDGET" class="MYCLASS"><a href="#" 
  onclick="alert(this.parentNode.getAttribute('headers')); return false">1</a></td>
```

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande made the changes, thanks for correction

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.anchor").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest("td").attr("headers"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
<td headers="2014_BUDGET" class="MYCLASS"><a href="#" class="anchor">1</a></td>

<td headers="2015_BUDGET" class="MYCLASS"><a href="#" class="anchor">2</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Alternatively, $(this).parent() instead of $(this).closest('td'). I don't know why, I just think it reads better. I'm not sure if there's any performance gain.

Comment: Yes we can use parent() function as well for this.

Comment: `$(".MYCLASS a").on("click"...`

Comment: Or just `$('.anchor').click(function(){//...})` - no need for `.on()`, unless they're dynamically added elements. - Many ways to skin a cat =)

Comment: Yes we can bind event in that way as well but i prefer to add separate class for that anchor because may be in future if you want to add another anchor in "td" element then you will also need to update this jquery as well

Comment: If "a" tag is adding dynamically then direct click event won't work. For dynamic bind you need to use "on" but yes in this example "on" is not required.

Comment: the `.anchor` was not available in OP's version. Hence my comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<td headers="2014_BUDGET" class="MYCLASS"><a href="#" onclick="alert(this.parentNode.getAttribute('headers'))">1</a></td>
```

It's essentially the same answer as Gurvinder372, however, that answer targets the A tag, rather than the TD tag.

1

### Edit

Never mind, he has updated his answer. Ignore this one.